FilePicker on Android can not show any files
I try use this filePicker https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/@angelengineering/filepicker/ for my Android Nativescript application
Manifest of my application allow me read storage
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

even I have add additional parameter to to manifest
<application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

I definitely have new files in my emulator. I need read JSON file, but may rename JSON to any file type to guarantee access to file.
There are nothing any options or special permission on filePicker, I perform it as
 pickedFiles = await filePicker(MediaType.NONE, false);


But I can not see any local files, even I'm sure that new file exist. Why? What going wrong?
In hamburger menu files also is absent


@Computable, thank you  for join to discussion. Yes, I write my file to /data/data/... directory. I expect this file would be accessible as new file in my device. For example in my phone I already have file explorer and any application (like Whatsapp or Notepad, or Music Player) allow me going to any folders on  my phone and pick up any files. I need to import files to my application, I expect this plugins (I used) allow me pickup file (even in /data/data), but unfortunately no. I can not understand why, I'm sorry. I have add screen for you, files in hamburger also is absent.

Are you aware that setting requestLegacyExternalStorage to true is only effective if the targetSDK of your app is set to 29? https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

@Robert, I set this parameter from description of package, I delete this setting now and nothing to change. Filepicker still don't allow open ANY location on phone and Android device still no tracing any changing files. Why? What going wrong?

My trouble was in parameter MediaType,nobody can assume that Android FileExplorer full collapsed and hide all tabs if we select MediaType.NONE. For shallow view JSON file not fit to IMAGE/VIDEO/DOCUMENT/AUDIO/ARCHIVE therefore I select NONE, but if I selected ALL - fileExplorer opened

